# Changing the input order for commands

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to write a simple bot that allows me to change peoples names by typing a command like this

```
.name @Someone new_nickname
```

Currently I have this function written up

```
@client.command(process_context=True)
async def name(ctx, *, member: discord.Member):
    print('{}'.format(member))
    await client.change_nickname(member, 'new_name')
```

However, the only way to invoke this command right now is to put the new nickname before the tagged person, like so:

```
.name new_nickname @Someone
```

So my question is, how do I write this function in a way that allows me to tag the person first, then write the nickname?

Comment: You're lacking a parameter for the new name. should be something like this `ctx,user:discord.Member,*,new_name`.
Also by adding `,*,` before a parameter name makes it so that all values after `,*,` will be converted into a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `pass_context`, not `process_context`.  You just need to put the `member` argument before a keyword-only argument for the new name:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def name(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, new_name):
    await client.change_nickname(member, new_name)
```